# INDEX MATCH in array formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm making a database in Google Drive. In one column I have abbreviations of a number of departments someone is in, but people can be linked to multiple departments. The abbreviations are comma-separated. I would like to have a formula that SPLITs the abbreviations at [,], then MATCHes the results to a range, and returns the full names of the departments.

```
abb      desired result
---      --------------
soc      Socrates
pla      Plato
des      Descates
heg      Hegel
heg,des  Hegel, Descartes
```

I've tried an arrayformula with INDEX and MATCH to no avail:

```
=join(", ";arrayformula(index(B$2:$D$7;match(split(F2;",");D$2:D$7;0);2)))
```

I've published a [MWE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ap6uG4C3OXPtdG1zakM3TG9sc210dVhRaWhPRmRGY0E&output=html) where you can also find an attempt with FILTER, but it gives the 1xN or Nx1 error, which makes perfect sense ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to be easiest solved with a script. If you have a list of philosopher names (column `A`) and their abbreviations (column `B`):

```
Name        | Abbreviation
--------------------------
Socrates    | soc
Plato       | pla
...
```

in a sheet named `Philosophers`, you should be able to use the following script function:

```
function getPhilosophersByAbbreviations(abbreviationsStr) {
  var philosophers = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Philosophers").getDataRange().getValues();
  var result = new Array();
  var abbreviations = abbreviationsStr.split(",");
  for (var a = 0; a < abbreviations.length; a++) {
    var abbreviation = abbreviations[a];
    for (var p = 0; p < philosophers.length; p++) {
      if (philosophers[p][1] == abbreviation) {
        result.push(philosophers[p][0]);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

In your data sheet, you enter the formula in column `B`:

```
soc     | =getPhilosophersByAbbreviations(A1)
pla     | =getPhilosophersByAbbreviations(A2)
des     | =getPhilosophersByAbbreviations(A3)
heg     | =getPhilosophersByAbbreviations(A4)
heg,des | =getPhilosophersByAbbreviations(A5)
```

... and the full names will be displayed in columns `B` and so on.

Feel free to play with [the example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Avea1NXBTibYdHAwQmFEMzQxMDZ4MlFWUVh5THpNOVE&usp=sharing) I set up.

Comment: That looks like something that could work, Vidar! I'll test it monday. I had hoped for a non-script solution. But if this works, I'll be very content!
When it does, I'll be sure to mark your answer as 'accepted'. Thanks in advance for you time!

Comment: That worked wonders! Thanks. 
I did use `=join(", ";getPhilosophersByAbbreviations(A5))` however, to prevent the output as an array. Looking back, that's exactly what I asked though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

A array formula (does not need to be, but appears to have been requested) that splits *pairs* up. Presumably could be extended to more than two departmental abbreviations in  single cell, but with GAS already provided that would seem masochistic:

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX($D$2:$D$7,MATCH(SPLIT($J2,","),$E$2:$E$7,0))&IFERROR(", "&INDEX($D$2:$D$7,MATCH(INDEX(SPLIT($J2,","),,2),$E$2:$E$7,0)),""))
```

Assumes the lookup table is in D2:E7 and the values to be searched for in J2:J6. The formula may be copied down from anywhere in Row2.